# .net or Xamarin Internet availability check when the WIFI network has no internet connection

Tags: android, ios, .net, xamarin, timeout

i know its a big discussion how to check if there is a internet connection available for the device.

I tried Ping, WebClient and HTTPClient.
I also use Xamarin Essentials and the Connectivity Plugin.

All this things are working, just make a request to google or the server of your choice and you will get back the answer or not.
You can also set a timeout for 2 seconds and so on.

But now i came to the situation where i'm connected to the WIFI BUT the WIFI itself has no active internet connection.

So all the things i wrote about was not working anymore. The problem is that the timeout will be ignored somehow. Maybe a bug in .net? I don't know.

Now i found one last thing:

```
try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com");
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Timeout = 2000;

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    //Connection to internet available
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Connection to internet not available
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            if (webEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

This was the only solution where i got the WebException when the 2 seconds timeout was reached.
In all other solutions i stuck more than 1 minute till the timeout was reached. Also when i set it to 500ms or something.

Did anybody know the reason why the given timeout is not reached for example with other methodes about?

Comment: did you get your answer to this? Is there any way to do this without sending a ping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can use `DependencyService`to implement it .Refer the following code.

> in Forms ,create an interface

```
using System;
namespace app1
{
  public interface INetworkAvailable
  {

    bool IsNetworkAvailable();
  }
}
```

> in iOS project

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Foundation;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IsNetworkAvailableImplement))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class IsNetworkAvailableImplement:INetworkAvailable
  {
    public IsNetworkAvailableImplement()
    {
    }

    bool INetworkAvailable.IsNetworkAvailable()
    {
        NSString urlString = new NSString("http://captive.apple.com");

        NSUrl url = new NSUrl(urlString);

        NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url, NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, 3);

        NSData data = NSUrlConnection.SendSynchronousRequest(request, out NSUrlResponse response, out NSError error);

        NSString result = NSString.FromData(data,NSStringEncoding.UTF8);

        if(result.Contains(new NSString("Success")))
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to allow HTTP access .add the following code in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

> in Android project

```
using System;
using Java.Lang;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IsNetworkAvailableImplement))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
  public class IsNetworkAvailableImplement:INetworkAvailable
  {
    public IsNetworkAvailableImplement()
    {
    }

    public bool IsNetworkAvailable()
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.GetRuntime();

        Process process = runtime.Exec("ping -c 3 www.google.com");

        int result = process.WaitFor();

        if(result==0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can call it in forms ,just like

```
bool isAvailable= DependencyService.Get<INetworkAvailable>().IsNetworkAvailable();

if(isAvailable)
{
  Console.WriteLine("network is available");
}

else
{
  Console.WriteLine("network is unavailable");
}
```

Comment: Hey Lucas Zhang,

we develop Xamarin iOS and Android native.
But your iOS code is working! It did not ignore the timeout in my special case that i'm connected to a WIFI without internet connection!
Great!
Thx again!
I will check the Android code later.

Comment: And some info. I use "https://" for captive.apple.com instead of "http://" so i don't need to add the NSAppTransportSecurity in the info.plist.

Answer (score -1):

**Edited:** Xamarin Essentials is the best solution as it offers more options, this is a sample of how to use it

- after setup Xamarin Essential NuGet in your project
- your code we be like the following

  ```
           if (Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity.NetworkAccess == Xamarin.Essentials.NetworkAccess.Internet)
           {
               //your Code if there is an internet
           }
           else
           {
               //your Code if there isn't an internet
           }
  ```

look at this:
https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials

Comment: Hello @Muhammad,

thx for your answer.

this is also not working correctly.
As i wrote about, this is working when you are in a wifi which provides an internet connection.
But when you are in a WIFI without an internet connection you will also get back:
Xamarin.Essentials.NetworkAccess.Internet

Its not working in this scenario.
Also the Xamarin Essential isnt working in this case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/

Comment: I get you, let's suppose that when wifi is available but no internet actually that means that you have a local network or limited access which also is supported in this plugin, I will try it now

Comment: Yes, right. We develop an app which is to configure some device. This device provide his own WIFI Access Point. When you connect to this network you will have a WIFI Connection but the network cannot provide you an internet connection, for sure.
But in this case, the Xamarin Essentials still return that you will have an internet connection, which is not correct.
I also tried this: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin but it has the same problem.